# jQuery How to 'smoothly' add a datarow to a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working with appending datarows. As they are appended, the entire tabe sort of 'jerks'.

Is there a way to smoothly append a datarow? I have the following: ([I also have a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bengal7/axkwj/3/))

```
jQuery:
```

var $trClone;

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    $trClone = $("#tblTest tr:last").clone();
    $trClone.attr('id', 'DataRow_' + i);
    $("#tblTest tr:last").after($trClone);
}
```

And the table:

```
 <table id="tblTest" class="schedule-table" cellspacing="1" border="0" style="width:100%;"> 
    <tablebody>
        <tr>     
            <td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Personnel</span></td>     
            <td class="resource-header"><span class="resource-header-text">Office</span></td>     
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Tue<br>01</span></td>
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Wed<br>02</span></td>
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>03</span></td>
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Fri<br>04</span></td>
            <td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sat<br>05</span></td>
            <td class="weekend"><span class="weekend-text">Sun<br>06</span></td>
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Mon<br>07</span></td>
            <td class="dow"><span class="dow">Thu<br>31</span></td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_3"> 
            <td class="resource" style="display:none;"><span class="resource">3</span></td> 
            <td class="resource" id="TD_Name">
                <div style="float:left;">Lname, Fname</div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img id="imgProgress1"  src="http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z137/Pixel_Pete/microUS.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Working..." />
                </div>        
            </td> 
            <td class="resource" id="TD_Office"><span>A6OK</span></td> 
            <td class="dow" id="TD_1" >Data1</td> 
            <td class="dow" id="TD_2" >Data2</td> 
            <td class="dow" id="TD_3" >Data3</td> 
            <td class="dow" id="TD_4" >Data4</td> 
            <td class="weekend" id="TD_5" >Data5</td> 
            <td class="weekend" id="TD_6" >Data6</td>  
        </tr>
    </tablebody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: <tablebody> ... never seen that tag... I've seen <tbody> tho.  Is it new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try fading it in. Or slideDown

```
$trClone.css('display', 'none').
$("#tblTest tr:last").after($trClone);
$trClone.fadeIn('slow'); //or slideDown.
```

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the input. I did try your code on the fiddle page but it doesn't seem to work. I like the idea though.

Comment: @bengal, I think it's something to do with the speed of the loop and the fade in animation. I fiddled a bit with the fiddle and got it working : http://jsfiddle.net/aXkWj/8/

Comment: @JohnP, thanks again for your feedback and time. I really do appreciate it. I checked out your fiddle, but it seems to be performing at the same rate as the original.

Comment: @bengal That's strange. It could be because the animation is done by the time the page loads :S Try really slowing it down `$("#tblTest tr:hidden").fadeIn(2000);` It fades in much slower for me.

Comment: @JohnP Hmmm, must be browser specific or something like that. I am running IE8 on Windows7. I appreciate your time. I'll mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Bengal, I don't have IE8. Was checking on chrome. Try integrating it into your app and post here if you have trouble. Also, have an alert() just before the fadeIn, that will show you the effect.

Comment: @JohnP It must be a browser issue. I adjusted the code and when I click an alert, the row shows up instantly http://jsfiddle.net/Bengal7/aXkWj/9/

Comment: @Bengal, you're code's wrong. Notice that in my fiddle I have the .fadeIn _outside_ the loop. See this link : http://jsfiddle.net/aXkWj/8/

Comment: @JohnP Right, I tried it like that at first, but no luck... they showed up instantly. Then I moved it inside the loop with an alert so I could see the effect on each row (I thought you meant that in your previous comment) but agian, each row shows up instantly

Comment: Have the fadeIn outside the loop, and have the alert just before it. If you still don't see the fade in, then you might have a problem. And don't put values that big in the timer!! You'd have to wait over 2 days for it to finish!! :D 5000 (ms) should be fine

Comment: @JohnP Right, I was just over-emphasizing the time. I tried what you said but no luck. I google around a bit and there seems to be an issue with IE8 and fading

Comment: hmm, curious. I'v used it before without any issues. You can still use any of the other animations. Or jquery's .animate() method

Comment: @JohnP, people are definitely having problems with fading in IE8 (search google). I did find one fiddle that works on my PC. Not sure what the diff is between his and mine http://jsfiddle.net/Cxvdk/1/